# MongoDB aggregate group by with condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

**Example documents**

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key1",
    "percent": 95
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key1",
    "percent": 50
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key2",
    "percent": 50
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key3",
    "percent": 50
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key3",
    "percent": 70
}
```

I want to extract document that percent less than 95.

When there are multiple documents with a specific key, that one is greater than 95 and one is less than 95, the document with that key must not be displayed. (In the above example, key1 corresponds. Because one is greater than 95 and the other is less than 95.)

And If all of multiple documents have a percentage below 95, the document with the highest percentage must be extracted.

**Current query that I used**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "percent": {
                "$lte": 95
            },
            "user_id": {
                "$eq": user_id,
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "max": {"$max": "$percent"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "percent": "$max"
        }
    },
])
```

**Result**

```
{"key": "key1", "percent": 50}
{"key": "key2", "percent": 50}
{"key": "key3", "percent": 70}
```

According to the conditions described above, `key1` should be excluded from the results because there are documents with a percentage of 95 or higher.

**Expected result**

```
{"key": "key2", "percent": 50}
{"key": "key3", "percent": 70}
```

Is this a problem that can be solved with MongoDB's query?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try checking the percent matching after the grouping (instead of before).

Comment: @prasad_ Correct! After changing order of match query, it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "user_id": {
                "$eq": user_id,
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "max": {"$max": "$percent"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "max": {
                "$lte": 95
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "percent": "$max"
        }
    },
])
```

After changing order of match query, it works perfectly.